# reactjs understanding dispatch for the below syntax

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have found something like below scenario using dispatch with redux

```
class SomeComponent extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        const { dispatch} = this.props
        dispatch(function1())
    }

    function1() {        
        return (dispatch, getState) => {
            return dispatch(function2())
            )
        }
    }


    function2() {        
        return (dispatch, getState) => {
            return dispatch(function3())
            )
        }
    }

    function3() {        
        return async(dispatch, getState) => {
            return dispatch(function4("ACTIONNAME"))
        }
    }

    function4(action) {        
        return {
            type: action,
        }
    }

    render(){
        return(
                <p> Testing</p>
            )
    }
}


export default connect()(SomeComponent)
```

As per my understanding when we use `dispatch(action)`, here action should be an object like `{"type":ACTIONNAME}`

but here its used as:

```
dispatch(function1())
```

and `funciton1()` returns another function and not action object

```
(dispatch, getState) => {
    return dispatch(function2())
)
```

its not `function1()()` that the returned function will get executed.

also the function returned, it has dispatch and getState as params, but how is it going to get them because `dispatch(function1())` does not pass any of them

Also looks like dispatch is being called so many times by the end.

Comment: Obviously, it’s the redux-thunk middleware, which allows action creators to be functions instead of plain object,these functions are asynchronous and can perform some side effects or multiple dispatches using the same action creator,as above, it’s like a chain of redux-thunk dispatches,hope that was clear.

Comment: Now i got it, So this is the `thunk` thing. Till now never bothered about thunk, just copy pasted code from others.

Comment: Yeah it’s obviously `thunk middleware`